# where is the Python icon in fontawesome

Tags: fonts, python, fontawesome

I'm trying to add the python icon
It appears to be in the font awesome font https://fontawesome.com/icons/python?style=brands to my document.

however it seems that there is no \faPython in the fontawesome package.

```
./template.tex:179: Undefined control sequence.
\x ->Python\faPython
```

It seems that the font had an update while the package hasn't seen any updates since 2016 (Version 4.6.3.2, released on May 22, 2016)

does anybody have any ideas on how to use the icon (other than adding it as image) ?

for referencing a working example

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt, onecolumn]{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}

\faTwitter %works
\faPython  %doesnt work

\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site, please provide a full, but minimal example showing your issue. Here we cannot see which packages you are using. (3) For example there are two versions of fontawesome on CTAN, `fontawesome` and `fontawesome5`, we cannot see which one you are using. Presumably the former as the latter was last updated in March

Comment: I've added a minimal working example.

Comment: `fontaewsome5` works just fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `fontawesome5` instead of `fontawesome`.

Interestingly the `fontawesome5` does not list the icons in the manual. But

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt, onecolumn]{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}

\faTwitter %works
\faPython  %doesnt work

\end{document}
```

compiles just fine under `pdflatex` using TeXLive 2018 frozen.

Comment: I had to delete TeXLive 2016 first as it was still using that instead of the 2018 version. But this works now. Thanks.